# Authentication failure when using mail Grails plugin

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

i'm using **Grails 2.5.1** and **mail:1.0.7** plugin to send emails , but when i'm using it i always getting the bellow error :

```
Class:javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedExceptionMessage:535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257 qq4sm4579366wjc.14 - gsmtp
```

although i can login with the provided credentials successfully from the browser !!

here are my configurations in the **Config** file :

```
grails {
mail {
    host = "smtp.gmail.com"
    port =465
    username = "****"
    password = "***"
    props = ["mail.smtp.auth":"true",
        "mail.smtp.socketFactory.port":"465",
        "mail.smtp.socketFactory.class":"javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory",
        "mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback":"false"]
}
}
```

and here is the action :

```
 mailService.sendMail{
        to userInstance.toEmail
        subject  userInstance.subject
        html "<strong>Test</strong> "
    }
```

anything i'm missing ?

Answer (score 0):

It may be because of gmail's security feature for less secure apps to get authenticated. Just turn on the access for less secure apps.

Follow below steps:

1 Login to your gmail account

2 Access the url:
 https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

3 Select "Turn on"

Answer (score -1):

If you have gmail - settings for plugin are correct (i have the same and they are working) , but *if your email is not gmail you must have other config*.

By the way if you gmail :

```
Username and Password not accepted.
```

your username or password is wrong, try to login with this Username and password, **watch out for register of letters.** 
https://grails.org/plugin/mail

Comment: i checked all the credentials by login in with it via the browser and it was working but nit working in my code and giving me the same error , is there something wrong with the mentioned configs ?